# How do I compare two txt files in python and save the duplicate occurances in a file

Tags: python

Tried looking for something like this, found nothing and this doesn't work. More specificly, I'm trying to compare a list of names to a wordlist to see if any of the names are words in the list. Also have tried using intersections; however that just returns set()

```
file_1 = set()
file_2 = set()

with open('output.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        file_1.add(line.strip())

with open('words_alpha.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        file_2.add(line.strip())

same=(file_1 - file_2)
samelist=list(same)
with open('some_output_file.txt', 'w') as f: 
    for item in samelist:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Comment: You just need to change the minus sign in line `same=(file_1 - file_2)` to the `&` sign `same=(file_1 & file_2)` so that it can get the intersection between 2 sets.

Answer (score 0):

If you did use intersections at some point, your code should generally have worked. You can shorten it here and there:

```
with open('output.txt', 'r') as f1, open('words_alpha.txt', 'r') as f2:
    file_1 = set(map(str.strip, f1))
    file_2 = set(map(str.strip, f2))

same = file_1 & file_2
```

Comment: still returns set() when i try to print same; i also want to save the duplicates to a file and i'm not sure if i can do that with a set